# Based on form combobox selection to open the another form and move the value

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am new to access.
I have DFR form, From DFR form we are copy the record to different history card based on the asset code.
So what I did now I create one button and generate the code to open the form based on combobox selction ( the combobox contain the assed code no).
AFfter complete the DFR form press generate button it is opening the form what asset code contain in the combobox but i dont know how to copy the value from DFR form to the opened to asset code form. Because all the time I am not opening the same form so in the VBA I am not able to mention form name. Please help me

**The code for the button:**

```
Private Sub Command632_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenForm Combo99.Value
End_Sub
```

according to the above command the form opened but iam not able move the value

For example I am using two form one is called as a DFR onother one is Mech_history card
in this case i know the designation form name. but above case i dont know the form name so please help me

Comment: I tried editing your question for spelling a little bit, but it's a lot of work, maybe you want to revise it yourself a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pass an argument to the form that you are opening. This is possible as follows:

```
Private Sub Command632_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenForm Combo99.Value, , , , , , "example"
End_Sub
```

Then in the form that is opening, you can use it for example as such:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Label0.Caption = OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Where it will set the caption of `Label0` to "example".

The OpenArgs argument is a single value, but you can pass multiple values by concatenating. This is already very well explained here: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/openargs/index.htm so it doesn't seem of added value of me to reword that for my answer here. Please take a look on that website.

Comment: hi, But i need copy several values from DFR, the values alwys changing based on the combobox selcetion or based on textbox

Comment: @user3627935 Please see my Edit to my answer and follow the link. Let us know if it still doesn't solve your problem and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the OP needs Me.Name as an OpenArg, so that the form that opened Combo99.Value can be referred to.